# Active Record Error messages form_tag Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, error-handling, rails-activerecord

I have a validation in my model like so

```
class Prediction < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :home_team, :away_team, :home_score, :away_score, :fixture_date, :fixture_id, :user_id

has_one :fixture

validates :fixture_id, :uniqueness => { :scope => :user_id, :message => "only one prediction per game is allowed, for each user" }

end
```

The idea being a user can only make one prediction per fixture, and if they try and submit another prediction for the same fixture then they get a message stating they cant as already submitted..

I am using form_tag like so

```
<%= form_tag controller: 'predictions', action: 'create', method: 'post' do %>
 <%= error_messages_for :prediction %><!-- Just added this -->

<% @fixture_date.sort.each do |date, fixture| %>
<%= date_format(date) %>
  <% fixture.each do |fixture|%>
   <%= fixture.home_team %>
   <%= text_field_tag "predictions[][home_score]" %> 
   <%= text_field_tag "predictions[][away_score]" %>

   <%= fixture.away_team %>  
    <%= hidden_field_tag "predictions[][home_team]", fixture.home_team %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "predictions[][away_team]", fixture.away_team %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "predictions[][fixture_date]", fixture.fixture_date %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "predictions[][fixture_id]", fixture.id %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "predictions[][user_id]", current_user.id %>
    <% end %>
```

Controller

```
def create
begin
  params[:predictions].each do |prediction|
    Prediction.new(prediction).save!
  end
  redirect_to root_path, :notice => 'Predictions Submitted Successfully'
end
end
```

at the moment im getting the rather ugly and not practical

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in PredictionsController#create

Validation failed: Fixture only one prediction per game is allowed, for each user
```

How do i get the error message to display on the page

I thought that this would work

```
<%= error_messages_for :prediction %>
```

as above but it doesnt

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use `save` which returns boolean and add you will have your model with appended errors.

`save!`, throws exception.

Comment: tried that, now the form just submits and gives success message, however nothing is written to the model, which i guess is a good start, but not quite there, alos i had to install dynamic_form to use error_messages_for as it has now been deprecated...any ideas? thanks

Comment: `Validation failed: Fixture only one prediction per game is allowed, for each user
` indicates your model needs some validation to pass.

Comment: You should be trying to save a record for same user_id and same fixture_id. You can save the same fixture_id but with a different user.

Comment: could you provide an example, not sure if i follow, you mean passing the current_users id along with the prediction?

Comment: I don't know about your fixture model. Neither what you want to save. But problem is you are trying to save two predictions with same fixture_id. I don't understand what a fixture is.